# Question about a minimum action problem

Tags: classical-mechanics

I am doing Exercise 5 Chapter 2 of Goldstein's Classical Mechanics and the problem goes as follows

> A particle is subjected to the potential $V = -Fx$, where $F$ is a constant. The particle travels from $x=0$ to $x=a$ in a time interval $t_0$. Assume the motion of the particle can be expressed in the form $x(t) = A+Bt+Ct^2$. Find the values of $A, B, C$ such that the action is a minimum.

So far, I have gotten the Euler-Lagrange equation from the following:
$$L = T-V = \frac{1}{2} m \dot x^2 + Fx$$
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = F\text{ , } \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot x} = m \dot x \text{ , } \frac{d}{dt}\Big( \frac{\partial L}{ \partial \dot x} \Big) = m\ddot x$$
Thus, for the action to be a minimum, 
$$F - \vec F = 0$$
and $\vec F = m \ddot x = 2Cm$
$$F = 2Cm$$
I don't know where to go from here, though. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the Euler-Lagrange equations

$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial x}
$$
which gives
$$
m \ddot{x} = F\,.
$$
This is then a pretty simple ode to solve, with solution
$$
x(t) = + +\frac{F}{2m} ^2\,.
$$
for some constants $\{A,B\}$.
Then to find $\{A,B\}$ explicitly, one applies the boundary conditions $(x,t)_{initial}=(0,0)$ and $(x,t)_{final}=(a,t_0)$ to get
$$
A=0\,,\quad B = \frac{a}{t_0}-\frac{F t_0}{2m}
$$

Comment: Wait wouldn't it be $a = Bt_0 + \frac{F}{2m} t_0 ^2$

Comment: yes indeed, I copied it wrong!